# Div se ubica encima de otro Div

Tags: html, css

Ahora mismo tengo 2 `div` con diferentes `ID` uno se llama **image** con un `color` de fondo **rojo** y otro se llama **logo** con un `color` de fondo **azul**.

necesito que el `div` de `color` **azul** no se superponga encima del `div` con color **rojo** cuando este tiene una altura de 390px, hay alguna de manera de hacerlo sin usar algún **`@media (min-width: 675px)`**...  se que es por la `posicion Absolute`, pero como podemos modificar la estructura para que no suceda esto...

```css
.content {
   height: 60%; 
   margin-top: auto; 
   position: relative;
  }

  #image {
   width: 350px;
   height: 112px; 
   background-color: red;
  }

  #content-logo {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0; 
   text-align: center; 
   padding-bottom: 20px; 
   width: 100%;
  }

  #logo {
   width: 140px;
   height: 110px;
   background-color: blue;
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="content-login vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="width: 60%;">
   <div class="content">
    <div id="image">
     IMAGE
    </div>
    <div id="content-logo">
     <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 40%;">
   <div class="align-items-center justify-content-center d-flex h-100">
    <h1>HOLA</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**PD:** necesito que los `div` mantengan la posición actual, es decir, el div Azul debe estar en la parte inferior centrado y el div Rojo debe permanecer centrado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `flex` con `justify-content: space-between` y `flex-direction:column`.

En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```css
.content {
  display:flex;
  height: 60%; 
  margin-top: auto; 
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction:column;
}

#image {
  width: 350px;
  min-height: 112px; 
  background-color: red;
}

#content-logo {

  bottom: 0; 
  text-align: center; 
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  width: 140px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="content-login vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="width: 60%;">
    <div class="content">
      <div id="image">
        IMAGE
      </div>
      <div id="content-logo">
        <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 40%;">
    <div class="align-items-center justify-content-center d-flex h-100">
      <h1>HOLA</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: usted es le mejor sin duda alguna, eso es lo que quería lograr, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar el `position: absolute;` a `position: static;` en el `div id="content-logo"` asi:

```css
.content {
   height: 60%; 
   margin-top: auto; 
   position: relative;
  }

  #image {
   width: 350px;
   height: 112px; 
   background-color: red;
  }

  #content-logo {
   position: static;
   bottom: 0; 
   text-align: center; 
   padding-bottom: 20px; 
   width: 100%;
  }

  #logo {
   width: 140px;
   height: 110px;
   background-color: blue;
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="content-login vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="width: 60%;">
   <div class="content">
    <div id="image">
     IMAGE
    </div>
    <div id="content-logo">
     <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 40%;">
   <div class="align-items-center justify-content-center d-flex h-100">
    <h1>HOLA</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: pero el div azul debe permanecer en la parte inferior del todo centrado, esta position Static simplemente lo deja fijo allí, la idea es que independientemente de la pantalla el div azul debe permanecer de todo en la parte inferior

Answer (score 0):

cambia los estilos de `content-logo` , agrega  `position: fixed;` solamente.

Le puse **100%** al `#logo` para que ocupara toda la pantalla

```css
.content {
   height: 60%; 
   margin-top: auto; 
   position: relative;
  }

  #image {
   width: 550px;
   height: 560px; 
   background-color: red;
  }

  #content-logo {
   bottom: 0; 
   text-align: center; 
   padding-bottom: 0px; 
   width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      /*z-index: 1030;*/
      width:100%;
  }

  #logo {
   width: 100%;
   height: 110px;
   background-color: blue;
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="content-login vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="width: 60%;">
   <div class="content">
    <div id="image">
     IMAGE
    </div>
    <div id="content-logo">
     <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 40%;">
   <div class="align-items-center justify-content-center d-flex h-100">
    <h1>HOLA</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```